# jQuery .load transition and sorttable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, sorttable.js

I have jQuery:

```
$("#loadBtn").click(function(){
    $('#div1').delay(200).slideUp('slow')
        .load
        ('page2.php #div2').hide().delay(300).slideDown('slow');
        return false;
    });
```

When #loadBtn (located in my #leftColumn) is clicked, it replaces #div1 with #div2 perfectly.  I have two problems with this code however..

**1) *SOLVED BY GINCHER* ---- I can't get the function to slide up #div1.  it always just instantly fades and slides down #div2.**
If I use jQuery:

```
$("#loadBtn").click(function(){
    $('#div1').delay(200).slideUp('slow')
});
```

that code will slide #div1 flawlessly, however as soon as I add `.load('page2.php #div2')` it breaks and fades away before sliding down.

**2) *SOLVED BY GINCHER* ---- I cannot get the tables in #div2 to sort using `sorttable.js`

I realize that scripts ran on page1.php upon load cannot be applied to elements that are loaded via AJAX.**

I have tried to call the new table after the load function is complete,

```
$('#div1').load('page2.php #div2', function() {
    var newTable = document.getElementById('#tableId');
    sorttable.makeSortable(newTable);
});
```

But that doesn't work. Just to see what would happen, I pasted the whole sorttable.js content into

```
$('#div1').load('page2.php #div2', function() { /*sorttable.js content*/}
```

That made the table work properly, because the function was ran after the content was loaded. what am I doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$('#div1').delay(200).slideUp('slow', function(){ $(this).load('page2.php #div2').hide().delay(300).slideDown('slow'); });`
   Do the load function after the slide up completed.
2. `var newTable = document.getElementById('tableId');` - don't add hashtag in `getElementById`.